# Which to use for game Development? SDL_Surface or SDL_Renderer

Tags: sdl2

I'm relatively new to game development compared to the pioneers in this field, and my question, as stated in the title is, Should I Be using SDL_Surface for game development or SDL_Renderer, I know that SDL_Renderer is the *new*, and more *efficient* way, but i still do have a doubt...

Thanks in advance...
Random Developer

Comment: Can you name any specific reason for your doubts?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat well the games before SDL2.0 were made using surfaces, thats why

Comment: It's like saying "Old games were written in assembly, so I doubt I should use high-level languages". :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SDL_Renderer` is hardware accelerated on most systems, and falls back to software rendering when hardware rendering isn't for some reason supported. `SDL_Surface`s are always software rendered, meaning that you'll always have worse (or in some rare and odd cases, equal) performance. There's really no reason not to use `SDL_Renderer` over plain old surface blitting.